# Getting a string to a certain length.

Tags: c, string, char, strncpy

I am currently working with a file name and I need to get the name excluding the extension. I have a separate function that determines the extension of the file but can't find a way how to get the name without the extension.

If I have the file name mylog.txt I only want to be able to get out mylog

I have tried the following

```
strncpy(fileNameWithoutExt, LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName,
    strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName-strlen(fileExtension)-1));
```

For some reason though, when I run this I only get `m`instead of the rest of the file name. I'm never going to know many characters are within the file name or extension so it needs to be worked out what section it needs to get.

So basically, the question how would I get the name of the file without the extension.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Watch your brackets. Don't you mean `strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName)-strlen(fileExtension)-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh?

Are you seriously subtracting the extension's length from the pointer you pass *to* `strlen()`? That seems dangerous and weird.

Also, you shouldn't use `strncpy()` unless you really need it's rather quirky semantics. Chances are you don't, and using it to copy part of a longer string is a pretty good way of failing.

A better solution is often to figure out the lengths, and use `memcpy()`:

```
char         out[WHATEVER];
const size_t len = strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName);
const size_t elen = strlen(fileExtension);
const size_t out_len = len - elen;

if( out_len < sizeof out )
{
  memcpy(out, LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName, out_len);
  out[out_len] = '\0';
}
else
  out[0] = '\0'; /* Make sure we get an empty output if filename won't fit. */
```

Note that this also uses `const` where appropriate, and stores the return value of  `strlen()` in variables of the proper type, i.e. `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This has been bugging me for ages

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are computing the strlen of a memory area **before** the logFileName string.

It seems that the len is incorrect     ;

```
strncpy(fileNameWithoutExt, LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName,
   strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName)-strlen(fileExtension)-1);

                                            ^
```

But the following code will  be far more readable.

```
int logFileNameLen = strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName);
int extensionLen = strlen(fileExtension);
strncpy(fileNameWithoutExt, LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName,
   logFileNameLen -extensionLen -1);
```

Simplify your code when you are looking for a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

`strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName-strlen(fileExtension)-1)`

to this:

`(strlen(LogRotateConfiguration->logFileName)) - (strlen(fileExtension)-1)`

Here you get the full `strlen` of the filename first, and then minus the `strlen` of the file extension, instead of getting the `strlen` of the logfilename-strlen(fileextension).